# ImportError: No module named pyttsx

Tags: python, import

I have installed `pyttsx` package from this source

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx

downloaded, extracted and installed as `python setup.py install`

but still i am getting

```
ImportError: No module named pyttsx
```

when importing `import pyttsx`

any help would be appriciated!

Comment: what version of python did you install it for?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, python 2.7

Comment: did it install without error? Also what os?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, DTVD's answer is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are better to use pip

```
$ pip install pyttsx
$ pip list
pip (1.5.4)
pyttsx (1.1)
setuptools (2.2)
```

and everything should be fine

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jul 20 2011, 02:32:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 (LLVM, Emscripten 1.5, Empythoned)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyttsx
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

DTVD answer is also correct.

but if you want to do it manually follow the steps:

```
tar xvfz pyttsx-1.1.tar.gz

cd pyttsx-1.1

sudo python setup.py build

sudo python setup.py install

exit
```

open the terminal again and type

```
sudo python
import pyttsx
```

now it will work fine.i think this is the answer you were expected.

note------
`pyttsx` is not a command ,it is a file.

first you have to download the file **pyttsx-1.1.tar.gz** from internet.
then move/copy it into home folder.
type `tar xvfz pyttsx-1.1.tar.gz` to extract the file and follow above steps.